# handling two search inputs in one html form

Tags: html, forms, input

i have a form style i wan to implement where i have two inputs "one for searching post titles" and the other "for searching locations" the problem is every time i make a search using the titles input the url looks thus "`search/?q=ajax&q=&submit=Search`" which returns no result, and when i search using the other i get "`search/?q=&q=ajax&submit=Search`" this returns results. im guessing this is because the last "q" is closer to the "&submit".

my question is,maybe using "js" is there any way to go around this to submit contents from both input not just one?

thanks for any help rendered
code rendering searches

```
  if query is not None:

        lookups= Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(location__icontains=query)

        results= post.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()

        context={'results': results,
                 'submitbutton': submitbutton}

        return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)

    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/search.html')
```

Comment: You can't name both search inputs the same. The server will not be able to distinguish between title and location. Do you control the server side API?

Comment: i tried renaming the first p but still no cjanges.. no i do nit have full contril. im making use of q lookups

Comment: First, you will need to figure out, how to use that API. Which url parameters are supported? What do they mean? Test the urls manually by entering them in the address bar or using a tool like curl. Only when you know how to use the url parameters you will be able to create the right urls from your frontend.

Comment: in my backend i just need to submit "q" with a query but now theres 2 of them

Comment: So what is the query format to request title AND location?

Comment: here it is '  if query is not None:

            lookups= Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(location__icontains=query)

            results= post.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()

            context={'results': results,
                     'submitbutton': submitbutton}

            return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)

        else:
            return render(request, 'blog/search.html')'

Comment: That looks like the code to build the request but I'm not familiar with that. I'm familiar with this: when you request the url `search/?q=THE_QUERY` your backend will use THE_QUERY to search for something (because q is the parameter to specify THE_QUERY). To search for "bananas" you would request `search/?q=bananas`. Is this how your API works?